# Python - Regex capture multiple fields and build a dictionary with them

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary

I have this in the HTML code:

```
"name":"London Street" dsakjhasfsa safksafas "north":"232","south":"12","east":"113","west":"9","curRoom":"110"

"name":"London Street" something asdgas dsakhdask "north":"0","south":"22","east":"131","west":"19","curRoom":"10"
```

I have try those with Regex, but somehow I'm failing somewhere.

```
\"name\":\"\A(...)\Z\"*?north\":\"(d+)\",\"south\":\"(\d+)\",east\":\"(\d+)\",west\":\"(\d+)\",curRoom\":\"(\d+)\"

\"name\":\"^(...)$\"*?north\":\"(\d+)\",\"south\":\"(\d+)\",east\":\"(\d+)\",west\":\"(\d+)\",currentRoom\":\"(d+)\"

\"name\":\"(...)+\"*?north\":\"(\d+)\",\"south\":\"(d+)\",east\":\"(d+)\",west\":\"(\d+)\",currentRoom\":\"(\d+)\"
```

And with those captures I want to create a dictionary like this:
{ key is current room, values [position 0: a list with neighbours [1,2,3], position 1 - the name of the room] }

I only know how to achieve this until a point, by assigning to variable the find for each room like this:

```
list_of_neighbours = []
number_south = re.findall('south\":\"(\d+)\"', url)
list_of_neighbours.append(number_south)
....
list_of_neighbours = [n,s,e,w]
dictionay ={}
for k, v in list_of_neighbours:
        dictionay[k] = str(number_current_room)
        dictionay[k].append(v)
```

but this doesnt add the room and have too many steps. 
The questions are: Its possible to be a shorter version? and How can I fix the regex find?Thanks

Comment: That looks suspiciously like JSON you're trying to parse, would it by chance have some `{}` braces around it?

Comment: @roippi yes, entire output is enclose in {}

Comment: but i dont see a problem because i use open(url).read() and the output is clear and i can capture it

Comment: Well, your regex in the example code should be a raw string, but without backslash-escaping the double quotes. Perhaps that's why the other part failed?

Comment: @tom zych i'm failling by  capturing the first string who has two words.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you should probably go with @roippi's answer in any case. But do read about raw strings; you will need to understand them if you use regexes much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to parse [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) with regex.  Don't.  JSON is basically *already* a dictionary, just stringified in a standard format.

Use the `json` module:

```
import json

rooms = json.loads(some_json_string)
```

Comment: I got it how it works. Thank you very much for the tip